# Auto build AST in recurrent grammars

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, pyparsing

I am developing a parser for process calculus. I am using [this pattern](http://sourceforge.net/p/pyparsing/mailman/pyparsing-users/thread/4E8B3555.1090404@cs.wisc.edu) to automatically create AST tree with parsed objects.

My problem is that because of recursive nature of my grammar in the resulting tree I get objects (AST nodes) that are not present in the parsed text.

i.e.

for `A = a.b` I get 
`[Procdef:{'rest': ([Choice:{'lhs': ([Prefix:{'lhs': (['a'], {}), 'rhs': ([Prefix:{'lhs': (['b'], {}), 'rhs': ([], {})}], {})}], {}), 'rhs': ([], {})}], {}), 'proc': 'A'}]`

but I would like this to be:

`[Procdef:{'rest': ([Prefix:{'lhs': (['a'], {}), 'rhs': ([Prefix:{'lhs': (['b'], {}), 'rhs': ([], {})}], {})}], {}), 'proc': 'A'}]`

The difference here is lack of `Choice` node. In my past projects I used my own AST structures and functions passed to `setParseAction`, then I would just check if rhs is null and pass tokens. With objects passed I do not know how to do it.

The simplified code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pyparsing import * 

class ASTNode(object):
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens
        self.assignFields()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ + ":" + str(self.__dict__)
    __repr__ = __str__

class Procdef(ASTNode):
    def assignFields(self):
        self.proc, self.rest = self.tokens
        del self.tokens

class Choice(ASTNode):
    def assignFields(self):
        self.lhs, self.rhs = self.tokens
        del self.tokens

class Prefix(ASTNode):
    def assignFields(self):
        self.lhs, self.rhs = self.tokens
        del self.tokens

class RasParser(object):

    def grammar(self):
        prefix_op = Literal('.').suppress()
        choice_op = Literal('+').suppress()
        lpar = Literal('(').suppress()
        rpar = Literal(')').suppress()
        define = Literal('=').suppress()
        Ident = Word(alphas.upper(), alphanums + "_")
        ident = Word(alphas.lower(), alphanums + "_")
        choice = Forward()
        prefix = Forward()

        process = ident | lpar + choice + rpar
        prefix << Group(process) + Group(ZeroOrMore(prefix_op + prefix))
        choice << Group(prefix) + Group(ZeroOrMore(choice_op + prefix))
        rmdef = Ident + define + Group(choice)

        rmdef.setParseAction(Procdef)
        prefix.setParseAction(Prefix)
        choice.setParseAction(Choice)
        ras = ZeroOrMore(rmdef)
        return ras

    def parse(self, string):
        oo = self.grammar().parseString(string, parseAll=True).asList()
        print(oo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = RasParser()
    model = "A = a.b" 
    print(model)
    p.parse(model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, those elements *are* in your expression, they are just degenerate versions (single operand with no operator).  The recursive definition means that a single process will be parsed as a degenerate prefix (a prefix with no operators), and in turn parsed as a degenerate choice (a choice with no operators).

You have defined prefix in a way that is right-associative. If you meant left-associative, then it should read: `prefix << Group(process) + Group(ZeroOrMore(prefix_op + process))`

Are '.'s really "operators" here?  Are you trying to support something like "A = b.(c+d)" ?  If not, then you might be better off with defining your base operand as `Combine(ident + ZeroOrMore('.' + ident))`, and then your addition as `operand + ZeroOrMore( '+' + operand)`. Or use operand as the base element in infixNotation (see next).

If this notation is really as you intended, consider using the `infixNotation` helper to define this grammar:

```
choice = infixNotation(process, 
    [
    ('.', 2, opAssoc.LEFT, Prefix),
    ('+', 2, opAssoc.LEFT, Choice),
    ]
rmdef = ident("destination") + define + choice("rhs")
```

`infixNotation` will take care of any ()'s overriding the defined precedence of operations.